# Google Sheet Script - Return header value if cell value found

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have a google sheet that contains header values in the first row.  I have a script that is looking through the remainder of the sheet (row by row) and if a cell is a certain color the script keeps a count.  At the end, if the count number is greater than a variable I set in the sheet the script will trigger an email.

What I am looking at trying to do, is to also capture the column header value if the script finds a cell with the set color?  I'm sure I need to create an array with the header values and then compare the positions, I'm just not sure how to do so efficiently.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();

  //Project Range Information
  var projectRange = dataSheet.getRange(6,3,lastRow-5,lastColumn);
  var projectRangeValues = projectRange.getValues()[0];
  var cellColors = projectRange.getBackgrounds();

  //Student Information Range 
  var studentRange = dataSheet.getRange(6,1,lastRow-5,lastColumn);
  var studentRangeValues = studentRange.getValues();

  //Pull email template information
  var emailSubject = ss.getRange("Variables!B1").getValue(); 
  var emailText = ss.getRange("Variables!B2").getValue();
  var triggerValue = ss.getRange("Variables!B4").getValue();
  var ccValue = ss.getRange("Variables!B5").getValue();

  //Where to Start and What to Check
  var colorY = ss.getRange("Variables!B6").getValue(); 
  var count = 0;
  var startRow = 6;

  //Loop through sheet and pull data
  for(var i = 0; i < cellColors.length; i++) {  
    //Pull some information from the rows to use in email
    var studentName = studentRangeValues[i][0];
    var studentBlogUrl = studentRangeValues[i][1];
    var studentEmail = studentRangeValues[i][2];
    var studentData = [studentName,studentBlogUrl];

    //Loop through cell colors and count them
    for(var j = 0; j < cellColors[0].length ; j++) { 
      if(cellColors[i][j] == colorY) { 

           /*This is where I feel I need to add the array comparisons to get the header values */

           count = count + 1;
      };//end if statement
    };//end for each cell in a row

    //If the count is greater than trigger, send emails
    if (count >= triggerValue) {
        //A call to another function that merges the information              
        var emailBody = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailText, studentData);
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: studentEmail,
          cc: ccValue,
          subject: emailSubject,
          htmlBody: emailBody,
        });
    } else {};
    //reset count to 0 before next row
    count = 0;
  };//end for each row
};
```

EDIT:
I have updated the above sections of the code to based on the responses:

```
//Header Information
var headers = dataSheet.getRange(4,4,1,lastColumn);
var headerValues = headers.getValues();
var missingAssignments = new Array();
```

In the for loop I added:

```
//Loop through cell colors and count them
for(var j = 0; j < cellColors[0].length ; j++) { 
  if(cellColors[i][j] == colorY) {
       //This pushes the correct information into the array that matches up with the columns with a color.
       missingAssignments.push(headervalues[i][j]);
       count = count + 1;
  };//end if statement
};//end for each cell in a row
```

The issue I am running into is that I am getting an error - TypeError: Cannot read property "2" from undefined.  This is being caused by the push in the for loop as the script moves to the next row.  I am unsure why I am getting this error.  From other things I have read, the array is set as undefined.  I have tried to set the array to empty and set it's length to 0, but it does not help.  I don't think I understand the scoping of the array as it runs through.

EDIT:
Figured it out, the "i" should not iterate.  It should read:

```
missingAssignments.push(headervalues[0][j]);
```

The end of the first for loop I clear the array for the next row.

```
missingAssignments.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the values of the entire sheet. Then use the shift method to get just the headers. It is hard for me to completely understand your intent without more information about your sheet. Let me know if I can provide more information.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
  //below gets the whole sheet and shifts off the first row as headers
  var fullSheet = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = fullSheet.shift();

  //then in your loops you can check against the index of the headers array
```

Comment: Hi Jordan,  Thank you for your answer.  It got me on the right track and if my header was in row 1, this would be perfect.  I needed to update the sheet and the header information I needed ended up in a different row.  I have updated some code, I was wondering if you knew why I might be getting a TypeError??

Comment: Got it, it was iterating on a 2nd variable that it wasn't supposed to.

Comment: I am not totally sure, but I think that is because the value that is returned from getValues is always a multidimensional array. You need to do something like var headerValues = headers.getValues()[0];

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheets with Apps Scripts is really slow especially if you have lots of data to read.

Check these [tips from Apps doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices):

**Use batch operations**

> Scripts commonly need to read in data from a spreadsheet, perform
>   calculations, and then write out the results of the data to a
>   spreadsheet. Google Apps Script already has some built-in
>   optimization, such as using look-ahead caching to retrieve what a
>   script is likely to get and write caching to save what is likely to be
>   set.
>
> You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in
>   caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating
>   read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script, read all data
>   into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in
>   the array, and write the data out with one command.
>
> Here's an example — an example you should not follow or use. The
>   Spreadsheet Fractal Art script in the Gallery (only available in the
>   older version of Google Sheets) uses the following code to set the
>   background colors of every cell in a 100 x 100 spreadsheet grid:

```
// DO NOT USE THIS CODE. It is an example of SLOW, INEFFICIENT code.
// FOR DEMONSTRATION ONLY
var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
  xcoord = xmin;
  for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    var c = getColor_(xcoord, ycoord);
    cell.offset(y, x).setBackgroundColor(c);
    xcoord += xincrement;
  }
  ycoord -= yincrement;
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

> The script is inefficient: it loops through 100 rows and 100 columns,
>   writing consecutively to 10,000 cells. The Google Apps Script
>   write-back cache helps, because it forces a write-back using flush at
>   the end of every line. Because of the caching, there are only 100
>   calls to the Spreadsheet.
>
> But the code can be made much more efficient by batching the calls.
>   Here's a rewrite in which the cell range is read into an array called
>   colors, the color assignment operation is performed on the data in the
>   array, and the values in the array are written out to the spreadsheet:

```
// OKAY TO USE THIS EXAMPLE or code based on it.
var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
var colors = new Array(100);
for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
  xcoord = xmin;
  colors[y] = new Array(100);
  for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    colors[y][x] = getColor_(xcoord, ycoord);
    xcoord += xincrement;
  }
  ycoord -= yincrement;
}

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 100, 100).setBackgroundColors(colors);
```

The

> inefficient code takes about 70 seconds to run. The efficient code
>   runs in just 1 second!
>
> If you're looking at the Spreadsheet Fractal Art script (only
>   available in the older version of Google Sheets), please be aware that
>   we made a minor change to it to make this example easier to follow.
>   The script as published uses the setBackgroundRGB call, rather than
>   setBackgroundColor, which you see above. The getColor_ function was
>   changed as follows:

```
if (iteration == max_iteration) {
   return '#000000';
} else {
   var c = 255 - (iteration * 5);
   c = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, c));
   var hex = Number(c).toString(16);
   while (hex.length < 2)
     hex = '0' + hex;

   return ('#' + hex + '3280');
}
```